# Display double vlan using pyshark

Tags: python, pcap, tshark, pyshark

How can you get a list of vlans if you have more than one, for example if i have this packet..

```
Layer ETH:
    Destination: 00:99:88:77:66:55 (00:99:88:77:66:55)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Address: 00:99:88:77:66:55 (00:99:88:77:66:55)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: 802.1Q Virtual LAN (0x8100)
    Source: 00:11:22:33:44:55 (00:11:22:33:44:55)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Address: 00:11:22:33:44:55 (00:11:22:33:44:55)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Layer VLAN:
    ...0 .... .... .... = CFI: Canonical (0)
    000. .... .... .... = Priority: Best Effort (default) (0)
    .... 0000 1100 1000 = ID: 200
    Type: 802.1Q Virtual LAN (0x8100)
Layer VLAN:
    Trailer: 8dbdde29
    ...0 .... .... .... = CFI: Canonical (0)
    000. .... .... .... = Priority: Best Effort (default) (0)
    .... 0000 0110 0100 = ID: 100
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Layer IP:
    ....
Layer UDP:
    ....
```

if I use pyshark i got only inner vlan.

```
>>> print cap[0]['vlan']
Layer VLAN:
    ...0 .... .... .... = CFI: Canonical (0)
    000. .... .... .... = Priority: Best Effort (default) (0)
    .... 0000 1100 1000 = ID: 200
    Type: 802.1Q Virtual LAN (0x8100)
```

I expect to get it the same as tshark :

```
tshark -r filename.pcap -T fields -e vlan.id

100,200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed this discussing on github: https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/80

The easy way to get double vlan is:

```
vlan1, vlan2 = pkt[1], pkt[2]
```

or explicitly:

```
vlan1, vlan2 = pkt.layers[1], pkt.layers[2]
```